# Intuition behind pivoting reducing roundoff error

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

What is the intuition behind reducing the round off error by pivoting when row reducing matrices? There is another very similar question on the site, however it provides only examples in which it is easy to see that the effect of pivoting reduces round-off errors.

I cannot intuitively wrap around my head that pivoting will (almost ?) always produce better results than simply not pivoting...

So what is the intuition behind this behavior? Are there any examples in which pivoting leads to worse results? If it always produces better results: is there a simple reason / proof?

Comment: I think the main idea is to divide by the largest number possible at each step, since the density of numbers in the IEEE floating point representation is much better in $(-1,1)$ than in any other interval on the reals

Comment: That should be the reason. The density of floating point numbers is better the closer you get to zero. Therefore by pivoting you will divide the rows by bigger numbers, i.e. obtain a more a precise result compared to multiplying the rows with big numbers (which leads to big entries in the matrix for which less points exist).

Comment: Pivoting serves mainly to reduce the growth factor, which affects the accuracy of the solution. Dividing by large pivots prevents the propagation of large numbers in the factors.